# Regular expression not filtering out digits

Tags: java, regex, web-scraping

Im using this line of code to extract all text between the two strings "Origin" and "//". I'm trying to exclude all digits but this doesn't work, It grabs everything including the digits. is my regex incorrect?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("ORIGIN") + "(.*?[^0-9])" + Pattern.quote("//"), Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: example would be better.

Comment: Your regex clearly does not do what your explanation suggests; can you at least see why? (hint: no quantifier on `[^0-9]`)

Comment: yea, I tried [^0-9]+ and that didn't work either. Im so lost!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you have no need to `Pattern.quote()` either of `ORIGIN` or `//`; what is more, the text in your question suggests `Origin`, not `ORIGIN`, so I'll go with that instead.

Try this regex:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile("Origin([^0-9/]+)//");
```

Note: it disallows any slash between `Origin` and `//` as well, which may, or may not, be what you want; but since there are no examples in your question, this is as good a solution as I can muster.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not clear.
1) If you want to get only the text (without any number) even if there is number in:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ORIGIN(.*)//");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll("\\d+", ""));
```

2) If you want to get text without number :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ORIGIN([^0-9]+)//");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find())
    ystem.out.println(m.group(1));
```

3) Something else ???????

E.g :

String : `ORIGINbla54bla//`

1) String : blabla
2) No result (Pattern does not match)